# Distinct volume label for ISO and EFI partitions using xorriso?

Tags: iso, bootable

I'm trying to use xorriso to build an ISO, with a precreated EFI image (created by `mkdosfs` with no volume name provided) controlling boot, that can be dd'd onto USB media and remain bootable. This mostly works pretty well:

```
xorriso \
  -volid "FooInstall" \
  -map /path/to/content \
  -boot_image any efi_path='/efi.img' \
  -boot_image any platform_id=0xef \
  -boot_image any efi_boot_part=--efi-boot-image \
  -boot_image any partition_table=on \
  -end
```

However, when I do this, the stable `/dev/disk/by-*/` directories (other than `by-path`, which depends on how the media is plugged in and is inherently unstable; and `by-id` entries with the name of the USB device vendor) don't have any links to the ISO9660 filesystem itself, but only to the entries in the GPT partition table it contains:

```
# stat -c'%N' /dev/disk/by-*/* | grep sdc | grep -Ev '[/]by-(id|path)[/]'     # comments
'/dev/disk/by-label/FooInstall' -> '../../sdc2'                               # EFI
'/dev/disk/by-partlabel/EFI\x20boot\x20partition' -> '../../sdc2'             # EFI
'/dev/disk/by-partlabel/Gap0' -> '../../sdc1'                                 # Gap0
'/dev/disk/by-partlabel/Gap1' -> '../../sdc3'                                 # Gap1
'/dev/disk/by-partuuid/30373931-3130-4130-b031-303030303031' -> '../../sdc1'  # Gap0
'/dev/disk/by-partuuid/30373931-3130-4130-b032-303030303031' -> '../../sdc2'  # EFI
'/dev/disk/by-partuuid/30373931-3130-4130-b033-303030303031' -> '../../sdc3'  # Gap1
'/dev/disk/by-uuid/0000-0001' -> '../../sdc2'                                 # EFI
'/dev/disk/by-uuid/1970-01-01-00-00-01-00' -> '../../sdc3'                    # Gap1
```

...so `/dev/disk/by-label/FooInstall` ends up as a symlink to either the final `Gap1` partition or the EFI partition on the image (exactly which seems to be unstable), instead of being a symlink to the ISO itself.

Similarly, if I assign an explicit UUID, the associated `/dev/disk/by-uuid` *also* ends up as a link to the `Gap1` partition, not the raw device (with its valid iso9660 filesystem).

**How can I get a stable link to the ISO9660 filesystem itself -- in the above example, `/dev/sdc` -- that can't end up referring to the EFI image or one of the `Gap` filler partitions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you experience is actually a bug in udev file
60-persistent-storage.rules which is supposed to be fixed now by
https://github.com/dsd/systemd/commit/dd1afeea4ed9b60b8a4d8b2a6d211f919cb5202e
Discussed in
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/14408

Without fixing the rule file, any partition without a LABEL, e.g. because
it has no filesystem, can steal the LABEL of the filesystem in the base
device.
So your EFI partition image would need a LABEL and no other partitions
except a mountable ISO partition should be present.

---

Well, you already found out how to work around. So the following is more
for the archives:

You may get a partition table with only mountable partitions by appending
the EFI filesystem image as partition instead of marking a file in the
ISO as partition.

```
-  -boot_image any efi_boot_part=--efi-boot-image \
-  -boot_image any partition_table=on \
+  -append_partition 2 0xef /...path.on.disk.../efi.img \
```

If you want GPT instead of MBR add:

```
-boot_image any appended_part_as=gpt \
-boot_image any partition_offset=16 \
-padding 0 \
-compliance no_emul_toc \
```

If you want to omit the efi.img inside the ISO 9660 filesystem:

```
-   -boot_image any efi_path='/efi.img'
-   -boot_image any platform_id=0xef \
    -append_partition 2 0xef /u/FERTIG/SX \
+   -boot_image any cat_path=/boot.cat \
+   -boot_image any efi_path='--interval:appended_partition_2:all::' \
+   -boot_image any platform_id=0xef \
```

(The need for cat_path=/boot.cat arises from a xorriso bug which i found
right now. There must be a "/" in the catalog path, and xorriso does it
wrong if cat_path= is not set and there is no "/" in efi_path=.)

Comment: Thank you very much -- both for the software and the explanation of the behavior I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Using MBR instead of GPT appears to be the only sure way to get this addressability.

```
xorriso \
  -volid "FooInstall" \
  -map /path/to/content \
  -boot_image any appended_part_as=mbr \
  -boot_image any partition_offset=16 \
  -boot_image any partition_table=on \
  -boot_image any efi_path='/efi.img' \
  -boot_image any platform_id=0xef \
  -boot_image any iso_mbr_part_type=0x83 \
  -boot_image any next \
  -append_partition 2 0xef "/path/to/content/efi.img" \
  -boot_image any efi_path=--interval:appended_partition_2:all:: \
  -end
```

...and also adding `-n OTHERNAME` to the `mkdosfs` commandline to disambiguate from the ISO volume name leads to media for which a `/dev/disk/by-label/FooInstall` link is created pointing to the ISO.